# How to destroy a static object from App Domain

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, static

I am building an application using WebAPI 2 that could see relative high traffic in the near future. The application basically allows users to take online tests.

I'm presenting the test to the user 1 question at a time, but I don't want to hit the database server for each question for each user. The tests never change once created. Any change means a new test gets created.

I would like to read each test from the database server only once and cache them on the web server as a static object so that all users who are taking that test are sharing that same data. This could save me 10's of thousands of database transactions at peak times. However, I don't want store every test that ever gets created forever. When a new test gets created, the old test is then obsolete, and I want like to wipe it out. I might just generally want to wipe it out periodically just in case.

Could someone provide any guidance on how to do this? I think I can populate the cache, but how do I destroy the static object? Just set it to null? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Congratulations, you found the second hardest thing in programming, just after naming things: cache invalidation. If you know when to invalidate your cache, then yes, just setting the relevant key to `null` will suffice. Some relevant code would help answer this question more specifically, but I doubt it hasn't been answered before.

Comment: After having thought about it, I'm not sure what happens if I have a static property on a non-static instance and the non-static instance goes out of scope? 

How do I store my cache so that is stays in memory?

EDIT: Never mind this. I'm confusing myself. :)